# Efficient access to image pixels in Java

Tags: java, image-processing

I need to write a resampling function that takes an input image and generates an output image in Java.

The image type is TYPE_BYTE_GRAY.

As all pixels will be read and written, I need an efficient method to access the image buffer(s).

I don't trust that methods like getRGB/setRGB will be appropriate as they will perform conversions. I am after functions that will allow me the most direct access to the stored buffer, with efficient address computation, no image copy and minimum overhead.

Can you help me ? I have found examples of many kinds, for instance using a WritableRaster, but nothing sufficiently complete.

---

**Update**:

As suggested by @FiReTiTi, the trick is to get a `WritableRaster` from the image and get its associated buffer as a `DataBufferByte` object.

```
DataBufferByte SrcBuffer= (DataBufferByte)Src.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
```

Then you have the option to directly access the buffer using its `getElem`/`setElem` methods

```
SrcBuffer.setElem(i, getElem(i) + 1);
```

or to extract an array of bytes

```
byte [] SrcBytes= SrcBuffer.getData();
SrcBytes[i]= SrcBytes[i] + 1;
```

Both methods work. I don't know yet it there's a difference in performance...

Comment: What would you like to do with the pixels that you retrieve from the image?

Comment: @px06 As said, I am writing a (custom) resampling function, but how can this impact the answer ?

Comment: The second begin a direct access to an array, I would say that it has to be faster. But I am not certain how faster it is. Glad it worked.

Comment: Sorry, it was obviously "being", not "begin".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (but not the fastest) is to use the Raster `myimage.getRaster()`, and then use the methods `getSample(x,y,c)` and `setSample(x,y,c,v)` to access and modify the pixels values.

The fastest way to do it is to access the DataBuffer (direct access to the array representing the image), so for a TYPE_BYTE_GRAY BufferedImage, it would be `byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)myimage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()`. Just be careful that the pixels are encoded on `byte` and not `unsigned byte`, so every time you want to read a pixel value, you have to do `buffer[x] & 0xFF`.

Here is a simple test:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY) ;
byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData() ;
System.out.println("buffer[0] = " + (buffer[0] & 0xFF)) ;
buffer[0] = 1 ;
System.out.println("buffer[0] = " + (buffer[0] & 0xFF)) ;
```

And here is the outputs:

```
buffer[0] = 0
buffer[0] = 1
```

Comment: (Not my downvote.) This doesn't work, the image remains unchanged.

Comment: Can you share your code please? I use it into my library everyday and it works perfectly :-)

Comment: And no worries for the down vote, I'm used to haters. Certainly the same guy that down voted your question

Comment: I've just upgraded my answer, you now have some code as example.

Comment: Yep, I can make this work, but there is no change in the BufferedImage.

Comment: Do you get the same outputs? If yes, then there a change in the image.

Comment: Actually, I now see a change in the BufferedImage, but when I save it to disk, that change is lost !?

Comment: No, that means that you have an issue with the way you save it. Maybe try to put (byte)255 instead of 1 on many contiguous pixels, the changes will be more visible.

Comment: I get it now: due to zooming out (my test image is large), my change was invisible ! Stupid me ! I will update my post.

Comment: A side note: Directly accessing the data via `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` and `buffer.getData()` is the fastest way to *directly access the data* (**assuming** that you're perfeclty sure about the image type, and how to interpret the returned array!). But it will make the image "untrackable", which roughly means that it will no longer be held in VRAM, and that *drawing* this image, for example, in a component with `graphics.drawImage(...)` will become much slower. (This may be not relevant for your particular case, but should IMHO be pointed out).

Comment: Another side note: I wrote a few more words about this at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75661/java-single-array-best-choice-for-accessing-pixels-for-manipulation/75667#75667

Comment: Yes, you're right. In my work I need the fastest way to access and modify the image, and I don't need to display it using the graphics. I did some tests, using the DataBuffer is at least twice faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the underlying buffer `yourimage.getData().getDataBuffer()` but it will require some conversion since this is one long array. You could find order of pixels by setting some elements to a extreme value and render the picture to see how the pixels are affected.

Comment: I also need to change the pixels, this is where I am mostly stuck. I have no problem computing pixel offsets.

Comment: The object that you get is a databuffer(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html), you can use setElem to set a value.