# How to create a new grey scale (BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY) image in java?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I want to create a grayscale image but problem is that how I can specify the value (0-255) for a pixel  and read it during reading the same image.

```
     BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height , BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            File file = null; 
            //create random image pixel by pixel
            for(int yHeight = 0; yHeight < height; yHeight++){ 
             for(int xWidth = 0; xWidth < width; xWidth++){ 
               img.setRGB(xWidth, yHeight, rgb);//here what values to specify 
               //for rgb (0-255)
                 }      
             }

//write image
             try{
               file = new File("D:\\Output.png");
               ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);

             }catch(IOException e){
               System.out.println("Error: " + e);
             }
```

and for reading the same image how can I get the same specified pixel value.

```
private static void marchThroughImage(BufferedImage image) {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();

        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);
           }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different parts in your question:

- First to read / write an image in Java, you should use Java.imageio using this simple code

  `BufferedImage image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/the/image")) ;`
  `boolean written = javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("where/to/write/the/image")) ;`
- Then to access / modify the pixels in your image, you should access the raster with getSample / setSample or if you need performance, you directly access the DataBuffer. Read my answer in this question:
  [Efficient access to image pixels in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727519/efficient-access-to-image-pixels-in-java/39730660#39730660)

Comment: I am not reading image. I am creating the new image. I can create new ARGB image which works fine `BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.BufferedImage.TYPE_‌​‌​‌​‌​INT_ARGB );   File file = null; for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)  {            for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)   {                                 
       a=50;r=50;g=100;b=0;  int pixel = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b; //pixel img.setRGB(x, y, pixel); } }`                                 But problem is in setting pixel by pixel value for TYPE_BYTE_GRAY image. how can I specify pixel value for each pixel

Comment: TYPE_BYTE_GRAY  uses range of 0-255 values for pixel .So how can I set pixel value for each pixel.                                                                                    `img.setRGB(x, y, pixel); `                                                                            here how pixel value can be calculated

Comment: thanks I have set pixel value using below code:                                     `BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height , BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY); byte[] buffer = ((DataBufferByte)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();‌​‌​ for(byte b:buffer){ buffer[counter]=(byte) pixel; counter++ }` **but it increase image size very much. Is there any other work around to create grey scale image pixel by pixel and set pixel value for each pixel manually with out increasing image size**

Comment: TYPE_INT_ARGB uses 1 int to encode an image, so 4 times 1 byte (1 byte per channel). TYPE_BYTE_GRAY uses a single byte, so encoding only from 0 to 255. To fill a TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, use the DataBuffer or setSample, but never setRGB (much slower). Moreover, TYPE_BYTE_GRAY are much smaller than TYPE_INT_ARGB.